# PostGIS cannot find rows in table 1 where linestring in table 2 intersects multipolygon in table 1

Tags: postgis, st-intersects

I am new to PostGIS.

I have two tables, first is a table with polygons containing areas of municipalities, the second table is one with all my bike rides and has a column with linestrings in it. Both have different SRID numbers.

I want to know which municipalities I've ridding through with my rides (for all my rides, and per ride). This returns nothing (there should be a couple of municipalities in it. What am I doing wrong?

table1 = municipalities (multipolygons, srid 28992)

table2 = rides (linestring, srid 4326)

```
SELECT 
   a.geom
   a.name
FROM 
   table1 AS a 
LEFT JOIN 
   table2 AS b 
ON 
   ST_Intersects(st_transform(a.geom, 4326), b.geom) 
WHERE b.id = <ride_id>
```

Another try that isn't working:

```
SELECT 
   a.name, 
   a.geom, 
   b.geom 
FROM 
   table1 a, 
   table2 b 
WHERE 
   b.id='<ride_id>' 
AND 
   st_intersects(st_transform(a.geom, 4326), b.geom)
```

Haven't found an aggregated solution either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested out a similar query using osm data but with an inner join and it seems to work:

```sql
SELECT distinct a.id, a.name 
FROM   county as a 
INNER JOIN cycleways as b ON ST_INTERSECTS(a.geom,b.geom)
```

Comment: Tnx, I created another column for the county where the srid matched the srid of the multipolyline and your inner join made it work. On the fly st_transform of the column didn't work.